# Is javascript injection of password in form safe?

Tags: javascript, networking

I want to use javascript injection in my programming to make my company work more efficiently. What I worried about is **leaking of password due to javascript injection**. Here's my question, ***is the code below are safe?*** Here's the code I am going to using.

```
document.getElementById("user_input").value="company_user_id";
document.getElementById("pwd_input").value="company_password";
document.getElementById("submit_input").click();
```

I understand that javascript is client side script and maybe the code above wouldn't do anything related to network. I have do checking traffic by using WireShark and browser network console. Both show me the result of code above didn't do any sending or receive task.

Why I am asking such question is I really want to make myself easy that javascript code above is safe.

Comment: Well, I mean the password will be in plaintext....

Comment: Where would you store this javascript file?  Now instead of the password only being in your head it's also in a file or script somewhere.  That is, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Thank you guys for mention me about the plaintext password. I have put too much efforts on coding, thank you for mention me about the most important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safe from what?

(whatever it is, probably not)

You're including a plaintext password in a javascript file. If this file is accessible to anyone that isn't supposed to know the password, you're basically making it useless.

Comment: Thank you for mention me about "How javascript file is stored". I have put so much attention of coding, forgot about the most importance part. I think I have to think again about the plaintext password problems.

Comment: @user2977920, don't try "fix" security or make it more convenient until you've very carefully considered exactly what is being protected, what kind of access it is being protected from, and by who. Even security experts get it wrong so I'd stick to standard practices.